# Call Batch over powershell with parameters

Tags: powershell, script, batch-file

How do i call a batch file in my powershell script with some parameters?
seperating them as strings and with a space wont help and when i do a cmd call to operate ist with cmd it wont do it aswell, maybe because its not executed as a admin?

Comment: Post your code and errors here so we can review it and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether your batch file requires administrator access rights. Just running the batch file from PowerShell should work, as long as you provide arguments as separate strings. PowerShell will call cmd to run it. If you want to run it elevated (with administrator access rights), firstly launch a PowerShell as administrator, and then run the batch file in it.